# How to debug an android application started from 'adb shell am start -D '?

Tags: android, debugging, jdwp

I need to debug an android application that is already installed on a phone. I am able to start the application in debug mode but I **can't connect** to the process using JDWP. I have try two different ways that both fail. (see following sections)

---

**Command line attempt**

1- Start the application

```
[...]sdk\platform-tools>adb -d shell am start -D -n "package/package.SomeActivity"
```

The application starts and a alert display "/!\ Waiting for debugger".

2- Open a JDWP port

```
[...]sdk\platform-tools>adb forward tcp:8000 jdwp:7602
```

3- Attempt to connect using jdb

```
[...]sdk\platform-tools>jdb -attach 127.0.0.1:8000
    java.io.IOException: shmemBase_attach failed:
        at com.sun.tools.jdi.SharedMemoryTransportService.attach0(Native Method)
        at com.sun.tools.jdi.SharedMemoryTransportService.attach(SharedMemoryTransportService.java:108)
        at com.sun.tools.jdi.GenericAttachingConnector.attach(GenericAttachingConnector.java:116)
        at com.sun.tools.jdi.SharedMemoryAttachingConnector.attach(SharedMemoryAttachingConnector.java:63)
        at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.attachTarget(VMConnection.java:519)
        at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.open(VMConnection.java:328)
        at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Env.init(Env.java:63)
        at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.TTY.main(TTY.java:1066)
Fatal error:
Unable to attach to target VM.
```

---

**IntelliJ attempt**

I have configure my local project to start the default Activity and uncheck the "Deploy application".

I also get the application started with the same alert but unfortunately the IDE doesn't connect to the remote process.

```
Target device: 42f7cc14e2acbfab
Launching application: ********/********.SomeActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "********/********.SomeActivity"
Starting: Intent { cmp=********/********.SomeActivity }

Waiting for process: ********
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Root the phone
2. Open a root shell

   ```
   (computer)$ adb shell 
   (phone)$ su
   (phone)#
   ```
3. Run `am` command

   ```
   # am start -D -n "package/package.SomeActivity"
   ```

This way you can debug any app, no matter if it has `android:debuggable` set or not.

Comment: I will have to try this soon. This could be very useful to debug application without source code.

Comment: If I type `adb jdwp` command, it returns nothing, so I can't connect debugger

Comment: This all is not working for me. Let's see ig Google can help me https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189615411

Answer (score 1):

The deployed application was configured with the [`debuggable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug) attribute set to false. The prompt given on the mobile phone was simply misleading.

Comment: If I run app using commands in this post and when I run `adb jdwp` it returns nothing.

Comment: @WSS Most likely you are not able to reach the debug port. Open a new question. The tooling for Android has changed a lot.