# How can I debug an Android application using ADB/AM?

Tags: java, android, adb, aide-ide

I am using AIDE as an Android IDE. This application built my project successfully and produced the corresponding APK file.

I would like to debug my project. Currently I:

- open a terminal emulator
- move to my android project (# not necessary action as app was installed )

  ```
  $ cd /sdcard/AppProjects/myproject
  ```
- start `adb`

  ```
  $ adb shell
  ```
- launch my application with `am`

  ```
  $ am start --user 10 -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.package.app/org.package.app.MainActivity
  ```

But how do I debug this application?

Comment: I found a similar question that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205262/how-to-debug-an-android-application-started-from-adb-shell-am-start-d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), you should use `start -D` to enable debugging. So you would use something like this:

```
adb shell am start -D --user 10 -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.package.app/org.package.app.MainActivity
```

Also, your application needs to be set as `debuggable` in your manifest (`AndroidManifest.xml`):

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Comment: And then what happens / how do you connect to it?

Comment: You can then use "activity manager (am) tool to perform various system actions, such as start an activity, force-stop a process, broadcast an intent, modify the device screen properties, and more". Check docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html ;-)

Comment: @tanius you're right, I fixed that